# Use BitmapDecoder in an other thread then where is created. (The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.)

Tags: wpf, multithreading, bitmap

So, i have a function that will load an image from disk async in an other thread ( big images will be loaded and I don't want the UI THread to be locked while loading).

Loading is done like this

```
  public override void LoadFile()
        {
            using (var imageStream = new FileStream(_filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                Decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                InitializeFile();
            }
        }
```

Then I want to use the Decoder on the main thread

```
   public List<ThumbnailModel> LoadPages()
        {
            var result = new List<ThumbnailModel>();

            foreach (var frame in Decoder.Frames) <--// this line throws exception
            {
                result.Add(new ThumbnailModel
                {
                    Name = _metadataLoader.GetPageName((BitmapMetadata)frame.Metadata),
                    Bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(frame)
                });
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Now here is the problem, whenever I reach the line where I try to access the Decoder.Frames it throws exception (The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.)

Is there a way I can use my Decoder in the main thread if not, the only possible solution is to load all the image information in the other thread?

Full code version :
    // this is the task, that calls the imageFactory LoadFile method - NewThread

```
  private async Task OpenFileAsync(string strFilePath)
            {
                var newFile = _imageFileFactory.LoadFile(strFilePath);

            if (newFile != null)
            {
                _imagefile = newFile;
            }
        }
  //image factory load file - NewThread
  public IImageFile LoadFile(string filePath)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath); // .tiff or .jpeg

            var file = new ImageFileTiff(filePath, _metatadaFactory, _metadataVersioner);

            file.LoadFile();


            return file;
        }
// ImageFileTiff LoadFile will create a decoder - NewThread
 public override void LoadFile()
        {
            using (var imageStream = new FileStream(_filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                Decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(imageStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

                InitializeFile();
            }
        }
```

After we have an IImageFile we call on MainThread(UIThread)

```
var pages = _imagefile.LoadPages();
```

Where LoadPages is the place where the app breaks. also called on UIThread
    public List LoadPages()
        {
            var result = new List();

```
        foreach (var frame in Decoder.Frames)
        {
            result.Add(new ThumbnailModel
            {
                Name = _metadataLoader.GetPageName((BitmapMetadata)frame.Metadata),
                Bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(frame)
            });
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: If you make your "loading" thread return Decoder, you should be able to access in the main thread. Without seeing all the code I can't really give an exemple.

Comment: @Ostas I will update the code in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you could simply return the decoder from the thread to be able to access it but your decoder is a TiffBitmapDecoder which inherits from DispatcherObject (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject?view=netcore-3.1).

So you won't be able to access it from a different thread than the one where it was created msdn:"*Only the thread that the Dispatcher was created on may access the DispatcherObject directly*"

What you could do instead is use the decoder in it's thread and return the final result:

I couldn't build on your sample since there was to much missing for me to test it but I built a similar project to give an exemple:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {

    }

    public TiffBitmapDecoder LoadFile()
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "tiff files (*.tif)|*.tif|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(openFileDialog.FileName))
        {
            //I didn't bother to check the file extension since it's just an exemple
            using (var imageStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile())
            {
                return new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //User cancelled
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<ThumbnailModel> LoadPages(TiffBitmapDecoder decoder)
    {
        //TiffBitmapDecoder" inherits from DispatcherObject/>
        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject?view=netcore-3.1
        var result = new List<ThumbnailModel>();
        if (decoder != null)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var frame in decoder.Frames)
                {
                    result.Add(new ThumbnailModel
                    {
                        //set the variables
                    });
                }
            }
            catch(InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Nothing to do
        }
        return result;
    }

    private async Task AsyncLoading()
    {
        this.thumbnailModels = await Task.Run<List<ThumbnailModel>>(() =>
        {
            var decoder = this.LoadFile();
            return this.LoadPages(decoder);
        });
    }

    private List<ThumbnailModel> thumbnailModels = null;

    private async void AsyncLoadingButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await this.AsyncLoading();
    }
}

public class ThumbnailModel
{
}
```

Content of MainWindow.xaml just in case:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button x:Name="NoReturnButton" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Call AsyncLoadingNoReturn" Click="AsyncLoadingButton_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I will test it next week and come with an answer if it helps my case, anyway thank you very much for the effort.

Comment: this won't solve my problem, as I have to return an interface from the LoadFile(), but your answer answers my question. I can't use the decoder in an other thread, so I will mark it as answer. Thank you